# Switching to Automated Testing from Development, is it good career move?

Tags: automated-testing, java, development-process

I have 2.3 years of experience in development (Core Java). Recently I Switched to a new company. I have experience only in core Java so I'm facing difficulty to get development project. Now I got project in Automation Testing. Development to Testing, Is it good career move ?

Comment: I'm in your same shoes, and wondering what's the career path for QA? Do they move to DevOps roles? BA roles? PM? What happens after 10 years, do they just become Sr.Qa Engineers?

Comment: Any role a developer could aspire to, so could a QAer. I know one QAer who became a Manager, then a Director, then VP of Engineering.

Comment: Marking as to Closed for: 1 - Too broad question | 2 - Opinion based. StackExchange is meant to receive more precise questions. There are other forums where discussions and open-ended topics are better received.

Comment: I voted to leave closed even though I didn't agree with the close reasons chosen, because it is a duplicate: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/resume-and-job-seeking-advice-career-change-from-development-to-testing/25334

Answer (score 4):

> Development to Testing, Is it good career move ?

It can be a terrific move, if you want a career in testing.

If instead you are only doing it because you are having a hard time finding a development job, it may not be so good.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends.**

I believe a person can be successful in any undertaking if(and only if) he really does it with passion and conviction.

Answer (score 0):

Since the beginning, software development automated processes or made it simplier to access information. Either way, you always needed people to test as it is part of the development life cycle. The more complex the product, the more QA processes/people were needed. It can vary from product to product. But you usually have at least few people verifying the quality of the product.

Your question is legit as you can smell where we are heading. Quality is being enforced right at the beginning of development, hence developers are asked more and more about automated testing skills and knowledge of BDD/TDD. Though it is still not yet applicable to all products, we live in a cloudish world where platforms allowing fast development is being introduced every now and then. This makes the market extremely competitive and those who cannot reduce their time to market can easily be crushed. Think about this scenario:

> Your company develops product X and has a QA departement that requires 1 month to test and validate a new release. If a bug is found, the whole thing has to restart plus the development of the fix.

And this:

> Now you have this company B who develops Y, a very similar product as yours. This hip company adopts a full DevOps/agile/etc. methodology where they push little changes to the users every day fully tested. A month QA process is untinckable here. Hence, the testers are developers part of the team.

For the career prospect, I would suggest you either be a tester part of "DevOps" team which will keep you QA but with the latest tools available. Or switch all together to developper. The best would be to start being QA part of the team and to progressively merge. I am not saying QA is dead, but in today's landscape, it is preferable to master automated testing ASAP for career sake.